# List of non-language characters for UTF-8

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8

I have a list of strings that can be in many languages, not only in English.

Is there a list of only **non**-language characters for UTF-8?

Looking at the following [UTF-8 categories](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm), I want to remove all characters (or replace them with " ") **except** **[L*]** categories.

I want to remove only these characters, how do I do that?

For example:

I have a string written in Russian and when I use split(), I get:

```
['\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82']
```

==> so all these are language characters

On the other hand, I have this string: "Maximum temperature allowed-70°C". when I use split() I get:

```
['Maximum', 'temperature', 'allowed', '70\xc2\xb0C']
```

==> so the `\xc2\xb0` is a non-language characters

Comment: What are *non*-language characters? That's not a well-defined term.

Comment: You've given a single example of a "non-language character", that's not enough to build any sort of rule on…

Comment: what about using the categories here? [link](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/index.htm)